# How to use foreignId-constrained with default value?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

It's just now that I noticed from the video tutorial that Laravel has this `foreignId`-`constrained`. So I try change my code from **method.1** to **method.2**, the table migrated but when I try to `db:seed`, the default value is not working (it returns an error below).

(Method.1)

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('status_id')->default(1);

$table->foreign('status_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('user_statuses');
```

(Method.2)

```
$table->foreignId('status_id')->constrained('user_statuses')->default(1);
```

(Error returned using method.2)

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'status_id' doesn't have a default
> value (SQL: insert into `users` (`username`, `password`) values (admin, $2y$10$S
> ZUIglBQG/HhS/18zn41GOcH8f.hZaNewmyoGJBfDQchfC6OWdx26))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints), you are calling methods in the wrong order:

> Any additional column modifiers must be called before the `constrained` method

```
$table->foreignId('status_id')->default(1)->constrained('user_statuses');
```